# yii addBetweenCondition in range with outer range

Tags: php, yii

I have some question about `yii addBetweenCondition`.

I used this code

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('date',$this->date1,$this->date2,true);
```

lets say `$this->date1 = '2015-09-15'` 
and 
`$this->date2 = '2015-09-17'`

but the result shows record that has date between `15` and `17` that is `16`,
what I want is `15,16,17`.
how to do that in `yii`.
thank you
***EDIT***
i forgot to say that i use that on model

```
function search()
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What database do you use (Postgres, MySQL, ... ?). If it is possible attach wider code context (it would be great to see whole search method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this condition for your requirement. And always bind parameters for prevent sql injection in your query.

```
$criteria->addCondition('date >= :startDate AND date <= :endDate');
$criteria->params = array(':startDate' => $this->date1, ':endDate' => $this->date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$criteria->condition = "date >= '$this->date1' AND date <= '$this->date2'";
```

or,

```
//use this if you are expecting null in any of $this->date1 or $this->date2
if ($this->date1 != null) {
     $criteria->addCondition("date >= :from"); 
     $criteria->params['from']=$this->date1;
}
if ($this->date2 != null) {
     $criteria->addCondition("date <= :to");
     $criteria->params['to'] = $this->date2;
}
```

I believe that your `date` field has a time component that might be the reason for your `addBetweenCondition` not returning expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Two things may be the issue.

1. Check that you are using a `findAll()` method; or some variant of that method to query your database with this criteria.
2. If you need dates `15`, `16`, and `17`... you could consider doing your asking for dates between `14` and `18` --- this is assuming MySQL's `BETWEEN` is not inclusive.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) it is inclusive.